# How to pass different HttpResponses within Python Azure Function?

Tags: python, exception, azure-functions, httpresponse

I'm trying to find the pattern for returning different `HttpResponse`'s based on checks throughout my HTTP Triggered, Python Azure Function.

**Example:**

```
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('####### HTTPS trigger processing an event... #######')

    def get_request_headers():
        thing_id = req.headers.get("thing-id")
        req_host_ip = req.headers.get("X-FORWARDED-FOR")

        return thing_id, req_host_ip


    def check_thing_id_hdr(thing_id):
        if (
            thing_id != None
            and thing_id.isnumeric() == True
            and len(thing_id) == 20
        ):
            return True
        else:
            # DO I RETURN THE HTTPRESPONSE HERE?
            return func.HttpResponse(
                'Thing ID header is malformed',
                status_code = 404
            )

    def check_req_host_ip_hdr(req_host_ip):
        if (
            req_host_ip.split(':')[0] != None
        ):
            return True
        else:
            # DO I RETURN THE HTTPRESPONSE HERE?
            return func.HttpResponse(
                'Host IP header is malformed',
                status_code = 404
            )

    request_headers = get_request_headers()

    if(check_thing_id_hdr(request_headers[0]) == True:
        check_req_host_ip_hdr(request_headers[1])
    else:
        logging.error('####### Thing ID header failed check. #######')
        # OR DO I DEFINE THE HTTPRESPONSE HERE? 
        func.HttpResponse(
            'Thing ID header is malformed',
            status_code = 404
        )

# OR DO I SOMEHOW DEFINE THE CUSTOM RESPONSE HERE?
return func.HttpResponse(
        'Custom Message HERE',
        status_code = Custom Status Code HERE
    )
```

I've tried the above patterns along with wrapping all internal functions with a big `try:`-`except:`, but none of them return the custom message.

Please advise.

Comment: Do it in the `main()` function.  In your code above, that would be at your third comment.  The [azure functions python developer reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#http-trigger-and-bindings) has a simple example similar to what you are trying to do...   Inspect the incoming request and construct an different outgoing responses appropriately.   Start with that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is below code what you want?

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    #For example, use the param as the condition.
    condition = req.params.get('condition')
    if condition == "success":
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Success.",
             status_code=200
        )
    elif condition == "not_success":
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Not success.",
             status_code=400
        )
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "No condition.",
             status_code=404
        )
```

Comment: Thank you both. I was unaware of that example in the docs.

Comment: In my `function.json` there are the commonly seen lines `"type": "http", "direction": "out", "name": "$return"`. However my code `return func.HttpResponse(status_code=409)` will always return HTTP/200. Does above Python code actually emit proper HTTP-status codes on Azure Function call?

Comment: Oh! There is a difference between `int(HTTPStatus.CONFLICT)` and `HTTPStatus.CONFLICT`.